# Where Are All the Snapshots?

Tags: objective-c, xcode

In Xcode 4 I often do File->Create Snapshots. Well, where do all those snapshots go and how do I go back to say, one of them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the Organizer window, go to the "Projects" tab. Select your project in the left pane and you'll see all your snapshots in the lower right pane.